# email-templates Images are shown in preview but not in Gmail

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, email-templates

I'm using [email-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates) package for sending styled emails. Everything seems to work fine in preview of email (preview option is given in package itself. it renders sent email preview in tab if placed true). but when I get email in my gmail account images are not visible. I can tell that paths / images in the setting / code exists because in preview everything is placed just right.

```js
    smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
      smtpTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        jsonTransport: true,
        auth: {
          user: 'sender.example@gmail.com',
          pass: '123123',
        },
      })
    );
    
    smtpTransport.use('compile', base64ToS3());
    
    const templateWrapper = new Email({
      transport: smtpTransport,
      send: true,
      preview: true,
      views: {
        options: {
          extension: 'ejs',
        },
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'email/html/events'),
      },
      juice: true,
      juiceSettings: {
        tableElements: ['TABLE'],
      },
      juiceResources: {
        preserveImportant: true,
        webResources: {
          relativeTo: path.join(__dirname, 'email/assets'),
          images: true,
        },
      },
    });
```

Here is my HTML template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Efys - Welcome</title>
    <style>
      html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      *,
      *:before,
      *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        line-height: 1.4;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      }
      .bg-brand-color-blue-dark {
        background-color: #033e75;
      }
      .bg-brand-color-gold-light {
        background-color: #f0ede6;
      }
      .bg-brand-color-gold-dark {
        background-color: #d0a345;
      }
      .bg-white {
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }

      .brand-color-gold-dark {
        color: #d0a345;
      }
      .brand-color-gold-light {
        color: #f0ede6;
      }
      .brand-color-blue-dark {
        color: #033e75;
      }
      .text-color-white {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      .text-color-black {
        color: #000000;
      }

      .display-block {
        display: block;
      }
      .margin-top-0rem {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      .margin-top-1rem {
        margin-top: 1rem;
      }
      .margin-top-2rem {
        margin-top: 2rem;
      }
      .margin-bottom-2rem {
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
      }
      .padding-full-1rem {
        padding: 1rem;
      }
      .padding-full-2rem {
        padding: 2rem;
      }
      .padding-top-2rem {
        padding-top: 2rem;
      }
      .padding-bottom-5rem {
        padding-top: 5rem;
      }

      .border-solid-black {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
      }
      .border-radius-half {
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
      }
      .border-radius-1rem {
        border-radius: 1rem;
      }
      .whitespace {
        white-space: normal;
      }
      .font-size-x1 {
        font-size: 1rem;
      }
      .font-size-x2 {
        font-size: 2rem;
      }

      a,
      a:visited {
        color: blue;
      }
      .text-decoration-none {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      ol {
        padding-left: 15px;
      }
      p {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      .strong {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      h3 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      h3 + p {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      .inline-icon {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }

      .flexbox {
        display: flex;
      }
      .flex-row {
        flex-direction: row;
      }
      .flex-nowrap {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
      }
      .flexbox .cell {
        width: 50%;
      }
      .flexbox .cell:nth-child(2) {
        text-align: right;
      }

      .maximum-width {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 36.25rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .logo {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 36.25rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .logo img {
        border: 0 none;
        outline: 0 none;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .footer > .flexbox .cell {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .footer > .flexbox .cell:nth-child(2) {
          text-align: center;
          margin-top: 1rem;
        }
        .footer > .flex-nowrap {
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .inner-cell.flexbox {
          display: block;
          max-width: 100%;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="wrapper display-block bg-brand-color-blue-dark padding-full-1rem"
    >
      <!-- logo -->
      <div class="logo display-block" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <img
          class="display-block"
          src="efy-registration-header.jpg"
          alt="abc def"
          style="border-top-left-radius: 1rem; border-top-right-radius: 1rem;"
        />
      </div>

      <!-- content -->
      <div
        class="content display-block maximum-width bg-white text-color-black padding-full-2rem"
        style="border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem; border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;"
      >
        <p class="strong">Dear <%= clientName %>,</p>

        <p>
          You have successfully registered for <%= efyTitle %> on <%= efyDay %> at <%= startTime %>
        </p>
        <p>Your Reference ID is: <%= referenceId %></p>
                <% if (displayAddress) { %>
            <p>Zoom link: <%= address %></p>
                <% } else { %>
            <p>
              Zoom link: You should receive an email update with the link to the
              live efy
            </p>
                <% } %>
        <h3>Zoom Instructions</h3>
        <p>To join a Zoom meeting on a computer or mobile device:</p>
        <ol>
          <li>
            Download the Zoom app from their Download Center
            <a href="https://zoom.us/download" target="_blank"
              >https://zoom.us/download</a
            >. Otherwise, you will be prompted to download and install Zoom when
            you click a join link.
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>

      <!-- footer -->
      <div
        class="footer maximum-width text-color-white"
        style="margin: 1rem auto 5rem;"
      >
        <div
          class="flexbox flex-row flex-nowrap"
          style="justify-content: center; align-items: flex-end;"
        >
          <div class="cell">
            <div class="flexbox flex-row flex-nowrap inner-cell">
              <div class="col" style="margin-right: 0.5em;">
                <img
                  src="logo_icon.png"
                  alt="abc def"
                  width="50"
                  height="auto"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                Villa 1, Alwasl Rd. <br />
                Alsafa 2 <br />
                Dubai, United Arab Emirates
              </div>
            </div>

            <p>
              <span class="strong brand-color-gold-dark">T.</span>
              <a
                href="tel:+97143809298"
                class="text-decoration-none strong"
                style="color: #FFFFFF;"
                >+971 (0)4 380 9296</a
              >
            </p>
            <p class="margin-top-0rem">
              <span class="strong brand-color-gold-dark">E.</span>
              <a
                href="mailto:info@example.com"
                class="text-decoration-none strong"
                style="color: #FFFFFF;"
                >info@example.com</a
              >
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="cell">
            <p>
              <span class="inline-icon"
                ><a href="#"
                  ><img
                    src="icon-facebook.png"
                    width="40"
                    height="auto"/></a
              ></span>
              <span class="inline-icon"
                ><a href="#"
                  ><img
                    src="icon-twitter.png"
                    width="40"
                    height="auto"/></a
              ></span>
              <span class="inline-icon"
                ><a href="#"
                  ><img
                    src="icon-instagram.png"
                    width="40"
                    height="auto"/></a
              ></span>
              <span class="inline-icon"
                ><a href="#"
                  ><img
                    src="icon-linkedin.png"
                    width="40"
                    height="auto"/></a
              ></span>
            </p>
            <p class="brand-color-gold-dark strong">@example.com</p>
            <p class="margin-top-0rem">
              <span class="strong brand-color-gold-dark">W.</span>
              <a
                href="//example.com"
                class="text-decoration-none strong"
                style="color: #FFFFFF;"
                >example.com</a
              >
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML of the email you receive? This could be a number of different things - gmail blocking the images by default, or maybe your paths aren't correct on the generated email, etc. Does the email work with any other email clients?

Comment: I suspect you're linking to a local file, not a file on a server, but it's impossible to know without the HTML of the email.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones  I attached the html. please have a look. thanks

Comment: The issue is that you're linking to a relative image: `<img src="logo_icon.png"` This needs to be a full URL in order for external email systems to load the correct image.

Comment: Can you also include the code for your HTML template `email/html/events`?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones it is a folder, that contains the html file whose code is already in question.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was the _generated_ HTML (i.e. what an email client is receiving), not the HTML template. Then it looks like the issue with base64ToS3 is that these aren't base64 images, so this functionality won't currently work. See how https://github.com/forwardemail/nodemailer-base64-to-s3/blob/master/example.js the `html` var has a base64 image as its source?

Comment: ok, I'll check in a while. and will get back to you. thanks for the time man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load an HTML page and use the image like below

```
<img
  src="icon-linkedin.png"
  width="40"
  height="auto"
/>
```

It actually tells the browser that, load the image from the same directory from where you loaded the HTML page.

Here comes the problem. When your email is loaded in the `Gmail` it will also tell browser the same and the browser will not be able to locate the image.

**Solution:**

If you are sending it from the backend. Then upload the image in any public url. You can upload the image in you frontend hosting and find the link. Then use the link directly. Your image need to be accessible publicly.

If you do not have any other option or hosting. Upload the image in any public github/gitlab repo and use the link.

Comment: I understand that but if you look into documentation of nodemailer-base64-to-s3 and email-templates they mentioned that we can attach local images –

Comment: I would never ever recommend doing that. From my previous experience I have seen many problems with that.

Comment: using static images sound good to me. what bad can come out of that? any idea?

Comment: I used email template from NodeJS and Django both.

Comment: The core problem can be the domain. When you will use the static image and if it sends url instead blob or base64 data. Gmail might block it. Which mean if your domain is not trusted enough. Also when developing in local static image will not be available in Gmail if it is not send as a base64 string

Comment: In my current development we use dynamic image. What we did is at first upload the image to the AWS S3 and then used the link in it. Using static image sounds easy. But that can have many problems in future. Also if any moment your server is inaccessible it will create problem to load the image

Comment: Finally if you search for best approaches for including images in the email template. Everyone will suggest to upload it in a secure public domain. I hope that makes sense

Comment: sure, It makes sense but I'm just looking forward to see it happening in static way. even if I end up using url based :)

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: though your answer is not entirely correct but it does have a logical point which any future developer in the same problem can easily see. so that's why marking it - thanks for your time dear

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs for `nodemailer-base64-to-s3`](https://github.com/forwardemail/nodemailer-base64-to-s3#options), you need to pass in some configuration options to the `base64ToS3` method. It says the `aws/params/Bucket` is required.

I believe the following should give you a good start:

```
smtpTransport.use('compile', base64ToS3({
    aws: {
        params: {
            Bucket: "bucket_name_here"
        }
    }
}));
```

See https://github.com/forwardemail/nodemailer-base64-to-s3/blob/master/example.js for another example.

Comment: I would recommend that if the email contained any dynamic or runtime uploaded image. from the implementation it is clear that all the images are static

Comment: yes, they do mention that, but only bucket name not enough, what are the other options and how to pass that. again problem with this might be it will add as many images to s3 as much we push email.